# Image export is 0 - 0 GEE NDWI

Tags: google-earth-engine, normalized-difference-water-index

Why does this code export result in a 0-0 range in the TIFF image? This is from a youtube author (**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8qrOc9zaaE**).

```
//Download & Visualize NDWI image using Landsat 8 

// 1. Import the Landsat 8 image
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA');

// 2. Get the least cloudy image in 2020.
var image2020 = ee.Image(
l8.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first()
);

// 3. Compute the Normalized Difference Water Index (NDWI).
var b3 = image2020.select('B3');
var b5 = image2020.select('B5');
var ndwi2020 = b3.subtract(b5).divide(b3.add(b5)).rename('NDWI');

// 4. Display the result.
Map.centerObject(image2020, 9)
var ndwiParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette:['red','yellow','green']};
var visPaaramsTrue = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max:3000, gamma: 1.4};
Map.addLayer(ndwi2020, ndwiParams, 'NDWI image 2020');
Map.addLayer(image2020, visPaaramsTrue, 'Landsat 8 image');

// 5. Export to Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndwi2020.int16(),
  description: 'NDWIimage2020',
  scale: 30,
  region: point,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The region set in the Export task is `point`. You didn't share the value of `point`, but I imagine this is a single `ee.Geometry.Point`.. so your image will consist of a single 30m pixel. Also, because you used `.int16()`, if the magnitude of your single pixel value is less than 0, then you will get 0.

If you want to export a more meaningful image, get rid of the `.int16()` (or scale your values first, e.g. `ndwi2020.multiply(10000).int16()`, and define a larger region to export.

Comment: thank you very much it helped 